# Struts action related issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I put a tag

```
<form action="/emailConfig.do">
```

in my jsp page
and 
put action in struts_config.xml file

```
    <action path="/emailConfig" type="a.b.EmailConfigAction" name="emailConfigForm" 
          scope="request" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/emailConfig.jsp" />
        <forward name="failure" path="/emailConfig.jsp" />
</action>
```

but when I perform any event (button click/ link click) page is not displayed but an exception appears that is

"The requested resource (/emailConfig.do) is not available."

Can anyone help me out what I am missing?

Comment: PS: System never reaches to Action class(I turned On debugger).It fails before that.

Comment: Did you restart the application server? How is your web.xml configured regarding the `ActionServlet`, specially the urlmapping. Sure it is '`*.do`'? The path to the `emailConfig.jsp` points to the webroot of your project.

Comment: yes I restarted it.Yes web.xml is set to .do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue already. I just replaced

```
 <form> tag with <html:form>
```

Happy coding! :)